# coverage of xml document with variables and paths

Tags: algorithm, code-coverage

For coverage, I've a set of run time variables of from my program execution. It happens that I get it from a series of executions(Automated testing). ie. its a `vector<vector<var,value>>`

I've a limited set of variables with expected values and generate combination s, that is I have `vector<vector<var,value>(smaller than the execution vector)>`. Now I need to compare and tell which of the combination I generated were exactly executed in one of the tests.

My algo is O(n^4). Is there any way to bring it down. Something like set intersection. I'm using java, and vectors because of thread safety.

Eloboration: I have a very big chunk of variables in my program. I don't care about all of them. All I care about is a set of variables with values that I know abt them(Edge values,and developer given values). What I do is, generate a set of combinations for those variables with values, which i think might be meaningful since, it will be useful after an automated test, to tell me that these combinations were excecuted and some were not.

Since, the test is automated i have a series (<20) executions with all variables and values in the DS I gave in the question. My problem is comparing a small set of combinations with a large set. The Hash might work if the no. of variables are same, i suppose. My algo is brute force

Comment: How does your algorithm do it? That would help me to understand your desired result better...

Comment: Vector is not thread-safe, read http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09263.html. I recommend looking in java.util.concurrent._ for an alternative, perhaps a CopyOnWriteArrayList? As stated by Jens your problem description needs a bit more information.

Comment: Perhaps an example run with some data values might make your question easier to understand.

Comment: @ponzao don't think that he uses Java

Comment: @Karussell it seems the description has changed a bit after my comment. Yes it doesn't look like Java anymore.

Comment: I'm sorry for not updating it. Its a java web service. I'm not monitoring the jvm. I'm just monitoring the webservice.  
I used some precomputation of variable order , to speed up the algo.

Answer (score 0):

I would generate hashes from the combination of  pairs such that if two  combinations are equal then they have the same hash.  If your set of expected  combinations is small then you could use this hash as a key to a Hashmap.

For each  combination in your execution vector, generate the hash key and look for it in the hashmap.  Hashmap lookup has amortized time O(1), so that for n execution entries and k expected combinations, the total time is O(n+k).

Some care must be taken in the choice of hash-function to avoid collisions, but this shouldn't be too hard a problem.